# Error Python not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo este codigo:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import FuncionesFiltros as fun

Im = Image.open('build.jpg')
Im_a = np.array(Im)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(Im_a)
plt.title('IMAGEN ORIGINAL')
plt.axis("off")

Im_cmy = fun.my_cmy2rgb(Im_a)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(Im_cmy)
plt.title('IMAGEN RGB A CMY')
plt.axis("off")

Im_rgb = fun.my_rgb2cmy(Im_cmy)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(Im_rgb)
plt.title('IMAGEN CMY A RGB')
plt.axis("off")


Im_hsi = fun.RGB_TO_HSI(Im_rgb)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(Im_hsi)
plt.title('IMAGEN RGB A HSI')
plt.axis("off")
```

-Esta es la funcion:

```
def RGB_TO_HSI(R,G,B):
    if(0<=R<=255 and 0<=G<=255 and 0<=B<=255):

        d = R+G+B
        r = float(R)/d
        g = float(G)/d
        b = float(B)/d
        numerador = float( 0.5 * ((r - g) + (r - b)))
        denominador = float(((r - g)**(2) + (r - b)*(g - b))**(0.5))

    if(b <= g):
        h = math.acos(numerador/denominador)

    if(b > g):

        h = (2*math.pi) -  math.acos(numerador/denominador )
        s = 1 - (3 * min(r,g,b))
        i = float(R+G+B)/float(3*255)
        rturn h,s,i
```

Cuando lo compilo me aparece un error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Por lo que entiendo es que se esperan 3 valores y apenas obtiene 2, pero no se en que parte estoy fallando. Si alguien me podria indicar el error lo agradeceria.

Gracias

Comment: Si no me equivoco la línea del error es `[row, col, nb] = Im_a.shape` (agrega siempre la traza completa del error, suele tener información relevante). Ten en cuenta que `Im_a` **es un array bidimencional**, la imagen en modo `L` es una imagen en blanco y negro a 8 bits (un pixel es representado por un solo entero de 8 bits), por lo que `shape` solo contiene el tamaño de esas dos dimenciones y tu intentas desempaquetar 3 como si el array fuera tridimensional (RGB o RGBA por ejemplo), donde `nb` serían los canales

Comment: A todo esto ¿Que es lo que intentas hacer?

Comment: Estoy intentado filtrar los colores de una imagen. Despues de esto tengo que ultiliar la funcion que definí:


def my_mseRGB(image1, image2):
    [m, n, b] = image1.shape
    n = m * n * b
    mse = sum(sum(sum((image1 - image2)**2)))/n
    return mse

Comment: Ya me carga las 2 primeras imagenes, pero me falta la transofrmacion a HSI